# How to disable the browser back button after the window alert

Tags: asp.net

```
   I need disable the browser back button after the window alert.
```

in page1.aspx i put like this

```
 **$(document).ready(function () {
             function disableBack() { window.history.forward() }
             window.onload = disableBack();
             window.onpageshow = function (evt) { if (evt.persisted) disableBack() }
         });**
```

After in Page2.aspx

```
 I put alert message when button click.once close the alert message i press the back button.
 same alert show when each click of back button.
```

**(How to prevent the alert message when back button press)**

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        history.go(1);
    };})
```

Comment: i try this same no change above

Comment: in which browser are you testing ?